# Struggling with Django syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-models

This drives me mad... I'm reorganizing an existing Django project using the following structure:

```
[project_abc]
  [app]
    [core]
      [app1]
        admin.py
        models.py
        ...
      [app2]
        admin.py
        models.py
        ...
      ... etc ... there's a total of 9 apps
    [rest]
      ... rest api stuff, non-db related ...
    [mobile]
      ... mobile stuff, non-db related ...
    [
  south
  tastypie
  [project_abc]
    settings.py
    urls.py
  manage.py
```

All apps with models that require database access have been added to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.admin',
  '[app].[core].[app1]',
  '[app].[core].[app2]',
  ...
  'tastypie',
  'south'
)
```

Each model class has a Meta class like:

```
class Meta:
  app_label=[app] # this points to the top level above [core]
```

Directories `[app]`, `[core]` and subsequent `[app]` directories have an `__init__.py` file in them.

When I run `syncdb`, it happily ignores my apps under `[core]` however the tables for other apps like `tastypie` and `south` get created properly.

When I run `manage.py validate` it returns 0 errors found

I've read probably all posts and hints on topics related to `syncdb` but unfortunately to no avail. I'm obviously missing something, but cannot figure out what it is....

Comment: I believe the app label needs needs to be unique per installed app. Have you tried just having them be `app1`, `app2`, etc, rather than `app` for everything?

Comment: Just tried that but unfortunately it makes no difference... Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not very clear what is `[app]` used in Meta? Is it added to installed apps? Does it conatin `model.py` file, possible empty? can you try to add empty `model.py` to core folder to make it django application, and add it to installed apps?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However I do not understand why. For example by adding django.contrib.admin one gets the admin tables for admin log created without the need for an empty models.py or adding an "empty" app to the installed apps... confusing. Add your comment as an answer and I will give you the credits.

Comment: app labels need to be unique; what is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: AFAIK app labels do not need to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully understand which `[app]` is set in models `Meta`, but note that django `syncdb` uses `django.db.models.get_apps` to find projects' applications. Latter interspects apps from INSTALLED_APPS, and explicetely tries to load apps' `models` module with

```
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
```

So applications outside `INSTALLED_APPS` won't have tables synced.

Second, django loads all the models with `django.db.models.get_apps` for each found application, and latter turn introspects `AppCache.apps_models` (that cache is, as far as I remember, populated with `register_models` by model constructor). So all the imported models corresponding to valid applications are processed.

I guess you have to ensure that `[app]` from `models._Meta`:

- contains `models.py` (possibly empty) which will make it a django application;
- is mentioned in `INSTALLED_APPS`, to be asseccible with `get_apps` function.